# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch - Google Computer Engine - nginx - SpringBoot - google OAuth

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, google-oauth, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt

I have a spring boot app running on 8080 (not https as I am not sure if this also need https enabled)
There is an nginx server that redirects requests from 80 (or 443/8443) to 8080

The nginx is secured using letsencrypt. I see this domain file in sites-enabled folder

created certificate using

> ```
> sudo certbot --nginx -d {dom}.co.uk -d www.{dom}.co.uk
> ```

```
server {

    root /var/www/{mydomain}.co.uk/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name {mydomain}.co.uk www.{mydomain}.co.uk;

    location / {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.{mydomain}.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
if ($host = {mydomain}.co.uk) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name {mydomain}.co.uk www.{mydomain}.co.uk;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

}

**OAuth 2 settings**

In OAuth Credentials

Authorized Javascript urls (For use with requests from a browser)

https://{dom}.co.uk

Authorized redirect URIs (For use with requests from a web server)

https://{dom}.co.uk/login/oauth2/code/google

**Configured redirect URL**

```
  private static API_BASE_URL = "https://{dom}.co.uk/";
  private static OAUTH2_URL = AppConstants.API_BASE_URL + "oauth2/authorization/";
```

**Question**:

How to fix my

Authorisation Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

**Do I need to make my spring app also https enabled**

(OR)

Any config issue nginx  or redirect url etc  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `redirect_uri` you send to Google when initiating the flow must match what you put in the console.

Here you have:

- `https://example.co.uk/oauth2/authorization/` in the code and
- `https://example.co.uk/login/oauth2/code/google` in the console.

Change either one to match the other. I suggest that you change your code to avoid waiting a good 5 minutes for the changes in the console to propagate.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did check and put the values from OAuth Credentials page and my spring angular app. Configured redirect URL and 1 line above it in the post. I never used nginx in front of my sprin app. So not sure how redirect url is coming as http:// ?

Comment: If you get the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error, nginx is not even called (check the logs or shut it down to confirm). Google refuses to complete the OAuth flow because `redirect_uri` sent in your OAuth2 request is not the same as the one in the console.  Show us more code where your variable `OAUTH2_URL` is used it might help.

Comment: I've fixed it just now. I made my spring app also letsencrypt enabled, and changed proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:8080"; to proxy_pass         "https://127.0.0.1:8443";